# I am seeing error during boot sequence on HP ProLiant ML350p Gen8

Tags: hp, boot, hp-proliant

The error states:

```
Caution: Memory conflict detected. You may face boot problem.
```

What steps would you recommend I take to troubleshoot this?

Details:
Dual Xeon E5 v1, two LSI 9286-8e RAID-on-Chip2208-based controllers, one LSI 2308 SAS6 HBA, Mellanox EN-3 NIC, Highpoint 1144C 4-port USB 3.0, AMD Radeon HD 46xx graphics

Latest BIOS and Option BIOS on each card

Comment: Where in the boot sequence?

Comment: I am booting with single Crucial M500 off of the Intel C602 onboard SATA controller (it's not production server yet).  I am not seeing a boot problem.  I see that one LSI 9286-8e RAID controller is dropping out in the middle of I/O test operation, while in Windows.  These issues might be unrelated.